# Wagtail - how to put two fields in one row in admin form?

Tags: wagtail

I would like to put two fields next to each other. I didn't find any instructions in the wagtail documentation so I think it's more tricky or not possible in the current wagtail solution. I suppose that the only way to achieve it is the override edit form the HTML file, right?

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need the `FieldRowPanel`.  Reference:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#fieldrowpanel